# Jquery mobile navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition returns the error code: error.PERMISSION_DENIED. how to solve this?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile, geolocation, gps

This is my code and it showing the error "User denied the request for Geolocation".
please help me to get the current location from google map or any way.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your position:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<div id="mapholder"></div>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
{
if (navigator.geolocation)
{
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
}
else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser."; }}
function showPosition(position)   {
 var latlon=position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude;

var img_url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
+latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML="<img src='"+img_url+"'>";}
function showError(error){
 switch(error.code)  {
case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
  x.innerHTML="User denied the request for Geolocation."
  break;
case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
  x.innerHTML="Location information is unavailable."
  break;
 case error.TIMEOUT:
  x.innerHTML="The request to get user location timed out."
  break;
case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
  x.innerHTML="An unknown error occurred."
  break;     } }
</script> </body>  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings on your browser.

Have you allowed the site to access the Geolocation?   This setting can be denied, one time only or always allow.

Comment: Again I getting an error "Location information is unavailable" after allowed the site to access the Geo location.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Check that you are using a html 5 browser.  See the list at the bottom of this link http://www.browsergeolocation.com/

Comment: i am using firefox 20 .. i checked with the url that you had sent.. But it is on loading infinetly